# Cannot access web server on Android from other devices

Tags: android, webserver

I have installed TinyWeb server on my Android. After starting the service, I can access it on the host device with the IP and port. But I can't access it from other devices when i create my own hotsopt.I use 127.0.0.1:8080 on my devices and it works. But not on other devices I also tried PAW Server. But its the same.

Comment: Make certain that there are no firewalls blocking communications between your devices.

Comment: Have you configured the TinyWeb server to listen on all interfaces (i.e.. not just 127.0.0.1)?

Comment: After some testing (installed it on my own machine) it appears the Tiny Web Server doesn't have any capability to serve whilst the phone is acting as a hot spot. It works fine if you're connected to another network (i.e. if you connect your phone and your client devices to your home broadband)